# Godot not opening

Tags: godot

Godot is not opening. I downloaded it from the [official website](https://godotengine.org/download/windows). I am on windows 10.
**Things I have tried:**

1. Updating my graphics driver ( I am running AMD )
2. Trying to open godot from the command line  ( No errors and even tried with the verbose command but with not luck)
3. Trying to specify a *OPEN_GL* version from the command line ( Still did not work )

It used to work before but I accidentally uninstalled it. Then when I reinstalled and tried again this happens.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming.

Comment: I have no clue what the problem might be. However, let me tell you that Godot makes a folder at %APPDATA%\Godot. There are settings, templates, shader cache, logs and stuff. I don't know if something there - perhaps some logs - can shed light into what is going on. And there is, of course, the nuclear option to remove the folder. However, I'm going to tell you to ask on the Godot community Q&A site. This is off-topic here, and hopefully somebody who can help you sees it there (or go to the Godot community chats). See https://godotengine.org/community

Comment: Will the godot engine reset if I delete the Godot folder

Comment: I deleted the %APPDATA%\Godot folder but it still refused to start

Comment: Well, that is that. It should create the folder again. Did it do it? Edit: If it did, did it make any logs?

Comment: It did not create the folder

Comment: I tried to run it with the verbose command from the command line and it still does not show any errors

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to try different versions. You could go older: In the download page, at the bottom is an option that says "Old Godot downloads" that takes you to https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/.  Or you can go newer, try the current beta: https://godotengine.org/article/dev-snapshot-godot-3-4-beta-2 (it is also listed on the other link) - Also, if you are on a 64bits try both the 64bits and the 32bits builds. I suppose you would avoid Mono given that you are having problems.

Comment: Even with the old and new versions the godot editor

Comment: I got this error

Comment: CrashHandlerException: Program crashed
Dumping the backtrace. Please include this when reporting the bug on https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues
[0] ???
[1] ???
[2] DrvSwapBuffers
[3] DrvSwapBuffers
[4] DrvSwapBuffers
[5] getEGLInterface
[6] DrvValidateVersion
[7] wglSwapMultipleBuffers
[8] wglSwapMultipleBuffers
[9] wglDescribePixelFormat
[10] wglChoosePixelFormat
[11] ChoosePixelFormat
[12] <couldn't map PC to fn name>

Comment: [13] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[14] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[15] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[16] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[17] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[18] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[19] <couldn't map PC to fn name>
[20] BaseThreadInitThunk
-- END OF BACKTRACE --

Comment: Godot 3.0 with both 64 and 32 bit

Comment: Godot does nothing out of the normal with ChoosePixelFormat. Do other OpenGL application (e.g. Blender) or games also have problems? - You could try display settings -> graphic settings -> classic app -> select Godot -> options -> change between high performance and energy saving. Or you could try running Godot with compatibility settings. You say you updated drives, but I'll say update drivers again just in case. You could also try a windows integrity check (sfc, dism). Otherwise you might need a firmware update. On that note, I remind you I'm just somebody on the Internet.

Comment: It still did not work and game the same error

Comment: Install it? Isn't it just a single .exe file? There's no installation required for godot

Comment: @Coolkid123-boop did you try the mono version as well just in case?

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall Godot and also check the anti virus configuration since Godot is not a verified program some anti virus software might not recognize it and prevent it from running

Answer (score 0):

Make a new .txt file in folder of godot
inside it write :-
[echo off
start Godot_v4.0.3-stable_win32.exe --rendering-driver opengl3]

save that .txt file as .bat and run
your godot will run absoluetly fine